# Why should we always throw new Exception? can we not store that exception as instance variable and throw the same instance everytime?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

In java, what I have seen so far is that whenever we throw an exception, we throw new Exception. Like the following example.

```
try{
    somethingThatCanGoWrong();
}catch(Exception e){
    throw new FailedToDoSomethingException("The other guy failed");
}
```

Is it always necessary to throw a new instance of an exception?
Can I do it the following way?

```
public class Blah
{
    private static final FailedToDoSomethingException failedToDoSomethingException = new FailedToDoSomethingException(
        "The other guy failed" );

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {
            somethingThatCanGoWrong();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            throw failedToDoSomethingException;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't prefer the last example because of 2 reasons.

1. Object orientally speaking, any Exception is neither a property of Class, nor the property of an instance.
2. Fails miserably in multithreading environment when the Exception message is dynamically generated and is based on method argument. Following is the example.

   `File getFile(String filePath){`

   `throw new FileNotFoundException("File at path: "+filePath+" was not found");`

   `}`

Are there any more reasons apart from the above 2? Is there anything that goes on behind the scenes when we create the new instance of an exception? something like populating the exception Context(like stacktrace. But I believe that happens when we use the `throw` keyword)?

Or is it just a good practice to throw a new Exception all the time?(Again, WHY is it a good practice?)

Comment: Exceptions are context specific. Think about `printStackTrace()`. Do you want to see the stack trace from some exception you stored at some point in the past, or do you want to see what caused the current exception to be thrown? If you don't throw a new Exception, all I can do is wish you the best of luck during your attempt to debug. "Best practices" aren't best because someone says so -- they're best because they provide the best outcome for you.

Comment: That was exactly one of my questions. So context is populated when you create a  `new` Exeption and not when you `throw` it?

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at here... The cause  is set at creation. Would you expect the cause of an Exception to change between the time it's created and thrown? Is there maybe some underlying question that you're trying to answer that led you to ask this question?

Comment: What do you expect to gain by creating and reusing an Exception?

Comment: Well I get it now. A simple experiment helped me understand this. I had a misconception that exception context like stacktrace is generated when we throw an exception. literally using `throw` keyword. But turns out, all of the context like stacktrace is generated when we create an instance of an exception.

Comment: @NomadMaker Nothing actually. I was just curious why :)

Comment: `The cause is set at creation` @MarsAtomic That was my misconception. I was thinking it is set when you throw the exception.

Comment: I had literally never considered this issue in 20 years, but it made me think, so thanks, Arun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stacktrace shows the line when the Exception was created, so you can't really see where it was thrown.

You can execute this example:

```
public class Foo {

    private static final RuntimeException re = new RuntimeException("MSG");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt("!!#!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```

When you take a look at the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: MSG
    at test.Foo.<clinit>(Foo.java:5)
```

You see that the line in the stacktrace is not the line where you actually throw the exception but rather the line were you call `new`